# Nginx Capture Request Headers

Tags: nginx

I'm testing out a CDN with my site. I'm running Centos 7 with Nginx 1.14.0. I've added the following lines in my Nginx server config:

```
server {
  ...
  ...
    client_body_temp_path      /tmp/nginx-files/;
    client_body_in_file_only   on;
    client_body_buffer_size    5M;
    client_max_body_size       7G;
  ...
  ...
}
```

My problem is that there are no files being generated in /tmp/nginx-files. I've tested this out in real-time while making requests to my site.
I just need to confirm the headers that are being sent from CloudFront to my server.

How do I catch the headers that are being sent to Nginx in an HTTP Request?

Answer (score 1):

Use tcpdump or some other packet capture tool?

The `client_body_` directives only apply to request *bodies*, not request headers.